# How to validate whether an array contains values from other arrays that are chosen by the user?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to validate an array against user-selected criteria which are four other arrays of: uppercase, lowercase, numbers, or special characters.

My passwordPool array combines the arrays that they chose to include in their password and then from there values are added to a final array in random order.

From there I am trying to validate whether all of the user-chosen requirements have been met and if not loop back through the password generator until they've been met.

I've looked at trying to compare the window.confirm responses to the final password, to compare the arrays to get confirm whether they have what they need, I've tried include()... I'm really not sure how to do this.

````
// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;

}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);

//Generate password
function generatePassword() {
  var pwLength;
  var confirmLower;
  var confirmUpper;
  var confirmSpecial
  var confirmNumber;

  //finding out how many characters the user wants in the password
  var pwLength = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between 8-128"));
  while (pwLength < 8 || length > 128 || pwLength == NaN || pwLength === null) {
    alert("That's not a number. Please enter a number from 8-128.");
    pwLength = prompt("Enter a number between 8-128");
  };

  //Defining variables
  var confirmLower = confirm("Do you want to include lower case characters?");
  var confirmUpper = confirm("Do you want to include upper case characters?");
  var confirmNumber = confirm("Do you want to include number characters?");
  var confirmSpecial = confirm("Do you want to include special characters?");

  //If all answers are false, looping back through to get atleast one true response.
  while (confirmLower === false && confirmUpper === false && confirmNumber === false && confirmSpecial === false) {
    alert("You need to select one type of character");
    var confirmLower = confirm("Do you want to include lower case characters?");
    var confirmUpper = confirm("Do you want to include upper case characters?");
    var confirmNumber = confirm("Do you want to include number characters?");
    var confirmSpecial = confirm("Do you want to include special characters?");
  }

  // Various Arrays
  var lowerCaseChar = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  var upperCaseChar = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  var numericChar = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
  var specialChar = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "{", "}", "|", "[", "]", ";", "'", ":", "<", ">", "?", "/"];
  var passwordPool = [];
  var randomPassword = [];

  //loop through chosen options to create a password
  function generateChar() {


    if (confirmLower) {
      passwordPool.push(...lowerCaseChar);
    }
    if (confirmUpper) {
      passwordPool.push(...upperCaseChar);
    }
    if (confirmNumber) {
      passwordPool.push(...numericChar);
    }
    if (confirmSpecial) {
      passwordPool.push(...specialChar);
    }
  }

  //create an array thats a pool for all selected values from char arrays
  generateChar();
  console.log(passwordPool);

  //create a final for loop that math.random.floors the array . the length of pwLength that meets the criteriaselected by user
  function pushChar() {

    for (var i = 0; i < pwLength; i++) {
      var item = passwordPool[Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordPool.length)];
      randomPassword.push(item);
    }
   

  pushChar();
  console.log(randomPassword);


    //at the end validate that all of the conditions were met. 

  } ```
````

Comment: Welcome!
First thing I've notices is `pwLength == NaN` = which is a problem, because `NaN` is NOT EQUAL to `NaN`, so the comparison will always evaluate to `false`, even if `pwLength` IS `NaN`.
Use `isNaN()` instead: `isNaN(pwLength)`.

Comment: To make sure `pwLength` is strictly a number string, well, consists of digit characters only, and at lease one, use: `pwLength.match(/^\d+$/)`.
All together:
`pwLength = prompt("Enter a number between 8 and 128");
while (!pwLength.match(/^\d+$/) || (+pwLength) < 8 || (+pwLength) > 128) {
  pwLength = prompt("Please try again: Enter a number between 8 and 128");
};
pwLength = +pwLength;`.

Comment: Notice that hitting escape on prompt will return `undefined` which is not the same as `null`.

Comment: Replace `(confirmLower === false && confirmUpper === false && confirmNumber === false && confirmSpecial === false)` with `(!(confirmLower || confirmUpper || confirmNumber || confirmSpecial))`, or `(!confirmLower && !confirmUpper && !confirmNumber && !confirmSpecial)` = clearer, less typing, etc... :)  They can only be `true` or `false`...

Comment: About `generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);` - where is `generateBtn` declared/assigned?  Hopefully, global variable.
(Don't rely on varables based on element's `id` - it could lead to troble)

Comment: In `function generateChar()`, may I suggest you randomly chose however many characters you want, from the arrays that correspond to the user's choice of type of characters?
Or, set flags for type, iterate through `randomPassword`, compare each item to types user wants (`includes`), until all flags are true = you are done...